# How to send props from createBottomTabNavigation to every tab screen?

Tags: react-native, react-props, stack-navigator, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am using createBottomTabNavigation and I have 4 screens which I can access by pressing the tab bar screen in the bottom of my screen. I am also using Stack Navigation to display the title of the screen there and also all screens have the same settings icon.

I could make the same function in every screen that takes care of onPress event on the Settings icon but that is repetitive and I don't want to do it.

My question is - is there a way for me to pass a function as a props from the App component which holds the bottom navigation to every screen?

App screen code:

```
<NavigationContainer >
 <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"  tabBarOptions={{
       activeTintColor: '#FF9F0A',
       inactiveTintColor:'white',
       style: {
        backgroundColor:'#000000',//color you want to change
          borderTopWidth: 0,
          paddingTop:5,
          paddingBottom:5,
       },
      
     }}>
   <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home}  options={{
         tabBarLabel: 'HOME',
         tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
           <HomeTabIcon name="home" color={color} size={size} />
         ),
       }}/>
   <Tab.Screen name="Controls" component={Controls} options={{
         tabBarLabel: 'CONTROLS',
         tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
           <ControlsTabIcon name="controls" color={color} size={size} />
         ),
       }}/>
   <Tab.Screen name="Charging" component={Charging} options={{
         tabBarLabel: 'CHARGING',
         tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
           <ChargingTabIcon name="charging"  color={color} size={size}/>  
         ),
        
       }}/>
```

Charging screen:

```
   function Charging() {
  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
      <Text>Charging</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

export default function ChargingStackScreen() {
  return (
    <ChargingStack.Navigator>
      <ChargingStack.Screen name="CHARGING" component={Charging} options={{ 
         headerRight: () => (
          <View style={globalStyles.headerRight}>
            <SettingsIcon />
          </View>
        ),
        headerTitleAlign:'left',
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerTitleStyle: globalStyles.headerTitle,
        headerStyle:  globalStyles.header
         }}/>
    </ChargingStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, pressing the Settings icon is supposed to simply navigate you to another screen, or do something else?

Comment: @RonB. Yes, exactly, pass me to another screen.

Comment: Good, and is it always rendered in the same place? e.g. in a header above your `Tab.Navigator` screens or something?

Comment: @RonB. Yes, always the same place for every screen - in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I think you should do is have the header as a separate component, where you can use the `useNavigation` hook (assuming you're using the latest version of `react-navigation`), and have the settings button do the navigation you need. Then just render the header component once above the `Tab.Navigator` instead of rendering it on every screen.

Something like:

```
function Header(props){
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    

    // component code
    <SettingsButton onPress={() => navigation.navigate(whatever)}/>

}
```

And then I am pretty sure (not 100% though) that you can render it in your `NavigationContainer`, something like:

```
<NavigationContainer >
<Header/>
 <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"  tabBarOptions={{
  // rest of the code
```